# How to get time sysdate time after insert Oracle Forms Builder

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

currently have this as a trigger when-create-record

```
:Transaction.Transaction_Date := sysdate;
```

it gets me the date but not the current time (10-APR-2020 00:00:00) and it displays on my display item before i execute query. is there a way to show the time when i execute?

Comment: `SELECT TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from  dual`

Comment: I haven't used Forms in a while (I miss it!) but isn't this a display format issue for the `:Transaction.Transaction_Date` field? http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/169892/ suggests the form field should be defined as `datetime`. Does it have properties you can go through and see if it has a default value and format?